# What should I do to build an offline web-based Phonegap app using http in loadUrl

Tags: javascript, android, http, cordova, offline

I use HTML5, CSS3 and JS in my Phonegap Android project.
In MainActivity.java I use:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

The JS functions do not work. However, when I host the web site and use:

```
super.loadUrl("http://......");
```

They work well.

I was asked to build an offline app, so I don't know what I should do to solve this problem.
I need helps, please.

Comment: What do you mean by js function don't work? put some js example where it is failing?

Comment: My project is an app using GIS Cloud map. And the JS function I used is in http://developers.giscloud.com/javascript-api/javascript-reference/. I used giscloud.center and giscloud.marker. Therefore, is it possible to embed a web server into phonegap app and load the url http://localhost.... ????

Answer (score 0):

You can add this property to config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

and then

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
```

Actually the default setting of PhoneGap should work without extra setting on Java.

Comment: I changed code like your answer and nothing happened.

Comment: When I run the index.html in my browser, it needs a web server to run JS functions. However, my Phonegap Android app is offline mode, I can not host all sites. Here my hosted web site and it runs well: http://luanvan.url.ph/www/index.html.